# Duda con BD relacional y unión de tablas

Tags: base-de-datos, modelorelacional

Buenas noches compañeros, me encuentro ante una problemática, tengo estas 3 tablas:

- usuarios
- viajes y
- destinos.

Un usuario puede unirse a x destinos de un viaje.

Para poneros un ejemplo:

> El viaje 1 tiene 5 destinos de los cuales el usuario 1 solo viaja a 2 de ellos, tengo que relacionar estas 3 tablas, mi idea era relacionar usuario con destinos pero me he dado cuenta que necesitaría el id de el viaje, el cual no está en la tabla destinos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Realmente lo que quiero en relacional es esto, pero no se bien como unir las dos tablas intermedias entre si con el modelo Entidad Relación

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: no deberia ser una tabla que fuera usuario-viaje-destino?? porque supongo que los destinos pueden pertenecer a varios viajes...

Comment: no entiendo, esas tablas ya estan relacionadas.. cual es tu problema?

Comment: se que quiero hacerlo así en modelo relacional pero no sé como se haría en el modelo entidad relación ya que las dos tablas que uno son tablas que surgen de una relación n:m ambas

Comment: sigo sin entender tu problema.. y sigo sin entender (si es que la hay) la diferencia entre modelo relacion y una entidad relacion.. que no es lo mismo?

Comment: Para que vieras diferencias entre el ER y el relacional, tendrías que tener alguna relación de cardinalidad 1:N en la que podrías prescindir de la tabla (relación) al propagar el campo (atributo) a la entidad. En definitiva que, como te indica @gbianchi, en tu caso coinciden. Salvo por el hecho de que no puedes unir directamente dos relaciones, es necesario crear una abstracción

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que vieras diferencias entre el modelo ER y el relacional, tendrías que tener alguna relación de cardinalidad 1:N en la que pudieras prescindir de la tabla relación al propagar el campo (atributo) a la entidad. En definitiva que, como te indica @gbianchi, en tu caso coinciden.

En el modelo de Chen no puedes unir directamente dos relaciones, es necesario crear una abstracción que puedes representar así:

[image: Modelo ER]

Nótese que este modelo ER está simplificado, faltan atributos y cardinalidades